# How to port forward port 25565 on airport time capsule

Tags: network, airport, time-capsule

I am trying to port forward port 25565 for a game server. I have tried to go into the port mapping settings, and creating one for 25565 on TCP and UDP and also reserving the ip on DHCP Reservations. The port still is not open as shown by http://portchecker.co/check and other port checking websites. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The port forwarding settings on Airport Utility require a private IP to be specified - is the port definitely forwarding to that IP address? Try setting it up as static on the device instead of reserving a dynamic IP.

Comment: I don't think that the port is forwarding at all because when I use port checker websites it shows that it is closed. Also, I had already set up my computer to have a static ip, and used that when creating the port mapping rule.

Comment: Is the port open on the destination machine? Check your firewall and see if you can access the port within your network (e.g. ping from another machine or try and join a game locally).